# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Identity Server 4 (4.0.0) SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'empty'

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0

I keep getting the following error between postman and IdentityServer 4

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'empty'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'MyNumberV2Api' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'empty'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'MyNumberV2Api' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler: Information: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'empty'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'MyNumberV2Api' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt was challenged.
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 1140.9671ms 401 
The program '[12792] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[12792] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff)..
```

1. In my Identity Server Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentityServer(
                options => { 
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                    options.IssuerUri = "http://localhost:5000";
                }
            )
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetAllApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                //.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.GetApiScopes());
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            });
        }
```

2. And here's the core for my API's startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ApiName = "MyNumberV2Api";
                });
            #region AddAuthentication
           
            services.AddDbContext<MyNumberV2.Data.MyNumberV2Context>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
           
            services.AddScoped<IAdminUserRepository, AdminUserRepository>();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader());
            });
            services.AddMvcCore();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseCors("Open");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

3. Here is my public repo for the full solution code: https://github.com/zachion/blazor-auth
4. Here is how I generate an auth token in postman:
   [image]
5. And here is the body section of my request to get the token where i add the **Grant type and
   Scope**.
   [image]
6. I get the token from the response and add it to the follow up requests for trying to get to the actual api's controllers.
7. Here is how I add the auth token in postman. Issuing the token works fine
   [image]
8. Here's the complete post man collection I use:

```js
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "089a85df-ae4b-41c3-8d1e-9d2e4ff8f7c8",
        "name": "MYNumberV2.Api Copy",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Generate Tokent API One",
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "basic": [
                        {
                            "key": "password",
                            "value": "secret",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "username",
                            "value": "client",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "grant_type",
                            "value": "client_credentials",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "scope",
                            "value": "MyNumberV2Api",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ],
                    "options": {
                        "urlencoded": {}
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:5000/connect/token",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "5000",
                    "path": [
                        "connect",
                        "token"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "api/adminuser",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disableBodyPruning": true
            },
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "noauth"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Authorization",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjNENDZERDNFQ0NGNTNCNkMyNEZEMjlFOUEzQzE2RjVDIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJuYmYiOjE1OTM0NTQyNTQsImV4cCI6MTU5MzQ1Nzg1NCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiY2xpZW50IiwianRpIjoiQ0QxQzY5QzVGRkI0MTA0RDU5MTUwNERFQkI0MkI3NjgiLCJpYXQiOjE1OTM0NTQyNTQsInNjb3BlIjpbIk15TnVtYmVyVjJBcGkiXX0.xvAs-IYh_sh8RmpNOcy4Rl78Jv2L2-vPE7FYeEVqxES2HBoTEEgPT7uV5MiZrVeK1OaLOrkERzZ4druHrBtKgaeJ-BoC_IUt5Lp_otnJVbmCgGtrPXk8RMKcZguvxQsJdD5rqHLNZaN07kMNQEmmAprSAPpixtErzMK5DEmaAee2PNi430AyiZnObYbUBm_07Un5_6cjpOSFltjzsABBOzsbWfXIbXwvynCUVEiN5_mHhhjgocPcvlzrHdDtUi_PbdBk_hhtouTlveIaCTyNGdhfR4JCTJjO069hVVCXHScrekjNPeRSC4eOFEesmdG-4IbPKWBLsKldc1SrC1DE-w"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "grant_type",
                            "value": "client_credentials",
                            "type": "text",
                            "disabled": true
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "scope",
                            "value": "MyNumberV2Api",
                            "type": "text",
                            "disabled": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "options": {
                        "urlencoded": {}
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:44340/api/adminuser",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "44340",
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "adminuser"
                    ]
                },
                "description": "https://localhost:44340/api/adminuser"
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "api/adminuserdetail/1",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:44340/api/adminuserdetail/1",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "44340",
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "adminuserdetail",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "description": "https://localhost:44340/api/adminuser"
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "protocolProfileBehavior": {}
}
```

Comment: How/where do you get this token from? I couldnt find it in your repo

Comment: I get the token from the identity server project running as console using also postman and is at: https://github.com/zachion/blazor-auth/tree/master/MyNumberV2.IdentityServer

Comment: how exactly you get that? feel free to post me snapshots - Reason I'm asking is that error you get is for using identity token instead of access token, I want to verify if this is the case for u as well or not

Comment: Hello Nahidf I have updated the original post with all requested snapshots.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is 2 issues in your code, I start from easy one to fix:

1. On your [API's startup class](https://github.com/zachion/blazor-auth/blob/master/MyNumberV2.Blazor/Api/Startup.cs#L99), move `app.UseAuthentication();` to be before `app.UseAuthorization();`. Proper order is critical for security. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order). Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030456/api-access-unauthorized-unless-authenticationscheme-is-specified/62035090#62035090)
2. Second issue is that on API you are asking for audience = `MyNumberV2Api` but if you check your current token on https://jwt.ms/ there is no `aud` as `MyNumberV2Api` in the token. Read more [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html?highlight=API%20resource#api-resources). To fix this we have two options:

   2.1. Change API to remove audience validation. To do this on API startup class use `AddJwtBearer` instead of `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` and set `ValidateAudience = false`.  After change code would be like this:

   ```
   services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer("Bearer",
                options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.Audience = "MyNumberV2Api";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new 
   TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });
   ```

   2.2. Add the audience to token. On IdentityServer - `Config.cs`, add the scopes to API resource:

   ```
   return new List<ApiResource>()
            {
                new ApiResource("MyNumberV2Api","Customer API for MyNumberV2")
                {
                    Scopes = new []{ "MyNumberV2Api" }
                },
                new ApiResource("ApiOne","Customer API for MyNumberV2"),
                new ApiResource("ApiTwo","Customer API for MyNumberV2")
            };
   ```

   After this change, if you regenerate the token there will be a property as `aud` with value as `MyNumberV2Api`. Check the token on https://jwt.ms/

I suggest you to test every thing on http first and then try on https. For http you may need to remove `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in your code and also clean up the `launchSettings.json` to remove https URLS and make sure `"sslPort": 0`.

Comment: My ApiResource was missing the Scope, Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the accepted answer. Instead of changing `AddIdentityServerAuthentication`, to use `AddJwtBearer`, IdentityServer 4 has support for older Validation. What helped me solve my issue was adding `options.LegacyAudienceValidation = true;` within my `AddIdentityServerAuthentication`.

Example:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("token", options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                options.ApiName = "API name";
                options.LegacyAudienceValidation = true;
            });
```

The *"token"* as the first argument in my method allows me to use *"Bearer"* Authentication. It also specifies the Authentication Scheme that you are going to be using. However, you will need to update your `[Authorize]` attribute to handle the *"token"* to `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "token")]`. The setup on the client-side won't change at all and is useful when co-hosting your WebApi with IdentityServer 4. More info here: [IdentityServer 4 Release Docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/add_apis.html)

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is correct however the provided solution did not add the audience claim to my token. So I solved it different.

The bearer token you used does not have the `aud` claim as already mentioned: [Here is your token at https://jwt.ms without the `aud` claim](https://jwt.ms/#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjNENDZERDNFQ0NGNTNCNkMyNEZEMjlFOUEzQzE2RjVDIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJuYmYiOjE1OTM0NTQyNTQsImV4cCI6MTU5MzQ1Nzg1NCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiY2xpZW50IiwianRpIjoiQ0QxQzY5QzVGRkI0MTA0RDU5MTUwNERFQkI0MkI3NjgiLCJpYXQiOjE1OTM0NTQyNTQsInNjb3BlIjpbIk15TnVtYmVyVjJBcGkiXX0.xvAs-IYh_sh8RmpNOcy4Rl78Jv2L2-vPE7FYeEVqxES2HBoTEEgPT7uV5MiZrVeK1OaLOrkERzZ4druHrBtKgaeJ-BoC_IUt5Lp_otnJVbmCgGtrPXk8RMKcZguvxQsJdD5rqHLNZaN07kMNQEmmAprSAPpixtErzMK5DEmaAee2PNi430AyiZnObYbUBm_07Un5_6cjpOSFltjzsABBOzsbWfXIbXwvynCUVEiN5_mHhhjgocPcvlzrHdDtUi_PbdBk_hhtouTlveIaCTyNGdhfR4JCTJjO069hVVCXHScrekjNPeRSC4eOFEesmdG-4IbPKWBLsKldc1SrC1DE-w)

To add the `aud` claim using in memory providers:
Make sure you add in memory identity resources that contains OpenId:

**Startup:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentityServer(/** your options **/)
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetAllApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources()) // !! ADDED
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.GetApiScopes());
    }
```

**Config.GetIdentityResources()**

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    yield return new IdentityServer4.Models.IdentityResources.OpenId();
}
```

This will add the `aud` claim to your token and enables validation.