# Getting 401 Unauthorized with valid access token using identity server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, authorization, identityserver4

I try to create a Identity Server with ASP.NET Core API. I have prepared an API:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetAllApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.GetApiScopes());
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseIdentityServer();
        }
    }
}
```

With config:

```
    public class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes()
        {
            return new List<ApiScope>
            {
                new ApiScope
                {
                    Name = "OpenIDApi",
                    Emphasize=true
                }
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetAllApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("OpenIDApi", "Customer Api for OpenID")
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = { "OpenIDApi" }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And an API:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<OpenIDContext>(opts =>
                opts.UseInMemoryDatabase("OpenIDDb"));

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ApiName = "OpenIDApi";
                });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

with controller:

```
    namespace OpenID.API.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly OpenIDContext _context;

    public CustomersController(OpenIDContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Customers
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> GetCustomers()
    {
        return await _context.Customers.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/Customers/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> GetCustomer(long id)
    {
        var customer = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(id);

        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return customer;
    }

    // PUT: api/Customers/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutCustomer(long id, Customer customer)
    {
        if (id != customer.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!CustomerExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Customers
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> PostCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        _context.Customers.Add(customer);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetCustomer", new { id = customer.Id }, customer);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Customers/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> DeleteCustomer(long id)
    {
        var customer = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(id);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Customers.Remove(customer);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return customer;
    }

    private bool CustomerExists(long id)
    {
        return _context.Customers.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
namespace OpenID.API.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
}namespace OpenID.API.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
}namespace OpenID.API.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
}namespace OpenID.API.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace OpenID.API.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
namespace OpenID.API.Models
{
    public class OpenIDContext : DbContext
    {
        public OpenIDContext(DbContextOptions<OpenIDContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

I obtain the token with Postman and them make a GET on the API to obtain the customers:[image: postman image]

As a result I get a 401 Unauthorized. What could be wrong ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Answered with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645604/asp-net-core-3-0-identity-server-4-4-0-0-securitytokeninvalidaudienceexception

Comment: Can you paste the token in https://jwt.ms and verify that you have "OpenIDApi" in the scopes property? You didn't document your token request. You need to request the OpenIDApi scope.

Answer (score 1):

Token should be passed as follows. Not as Headers in Postman.

[image]